# Sort 2D array using insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, insertion-sort

I want to sort a 2D array of integers by a certain column using insertion sort. The following code works for 1D array.

```
private static void InsertionSort(int[] a, int n) {

    int key, j;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            key = a[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while ((j >= 0) && (a[j] > key)){
                a[j+1] = a[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            a[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

For 2D array, I specify an integer c for the column by which to sort the array. For example, if I sort by the first column,

```
{4, 1, 3},
{6, 0, 2},
{5, 9, 8}
```

becomes

```
{4, 1, 3},
{5, 9, 8},
{6, 0, 2}
```

This is what I got so far for sorting a 2D array by a specified column

```
private static void InsertionSort(int[][] a, int n, int c) {

    in key, j;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        key = a[i][c];
        j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (a[j][c] > key)){
            a[j+1][c] = a[j][c];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        a[j+1][c] = key;
    }
}
```

but the result for sorting by the first column is

```
{4, 1, 3}
{5, 0, 2}
{6, 9, 8}
```

It sorts the elements of the first column without keeping them together with their respective rows. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap data row, not just the data element.

```
private static void sort(int[][] a, int n, int c) {
    int key, j;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        key = a[i][c];
        int[] keyRow = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (a[j][c] > key)){
            //a[j+1][c] = a[j][c];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        //a[j+1][c] = key;
        a[j+1] = keyRow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8, you could do it in one line.

```
Arrays.sort(data, (a, b) -> a[COL] - b[COL]);
```

where COL is the column to sort.